# What is the difference between Natural frequency and Resonant frequency?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, definition, frequency, oscillators, resonance

I was previously under the impression that natural and resonant frequencies are the same. However, after doing some research they don't appear to be the exact same. Could someone please explain the difference between them please.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153197/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228279/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/682059/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353053/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Resonance can be defined in different ways. Two of the commonest are (a) when the amplitude of the steady-state forced oscillations is a maximum (for a given amplitude of applied periodic force), and (b) when the mean power absorbed by the oscillatory system from the applied periodic force is a maximum (for a given amplitude of applied periodic force). If the damping in the oscillatory system is very small, the different types of resonance all occur at frequencies very close to the system's natural frequency, so it's hardly wrong to say that the resonance frequency *is* the natural frequency.

Comment: If the damping in the oscillatory system is very small, the different types of resonance all occur at frequencies very close to the system's natural frequency, so it's hardly wrong to say that the resonance frequency *is* the natural frequency. And this is fine for A level.