# How to mathematically prove that a linear system's vibration frequency is equal to frequency of the harmonic external force?

Tags: fourier-transform, resonance, vibrations, linear-systems

I was reading about ["Vibration" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibration#Types_of_vibration):

> Forced vibration: 'for linear systems, the **frequency of the steady-state vibration response** resulting from the application of a periodic, harmonic input is equal to **the frequency of the applied force or motion**, with the response magnitude being dependent on the actual mechanical system.'

I would like to enquire the detailed mathematical proof of this conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Fourier transform $t\leftrightarrow \omega$ the [damped forced linear oscillator](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=damped+forced+oscillator), which is a linear second-order [ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation). For more details, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/228451/2451).
2. Show that there are at most 3 (possibly complex) frequencies with non-zero amplitudes: 2 characteristic frequencies and the driven frequency.
3. All realistic systems contain dissipation, so the characteristic frequencies will die out. Hence only the driven frequency remains.

Answer (score 2):

Best approached using [linear system's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system) and [transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) analysis.

A linear system (which can be modeled as a [rational polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) transfer function in either $s$ or $j\omega$) responds to a linear excitation resulting in response having the same frequency however possibly different phase and amplitude.

This can be shown in a very generalized fashion either in the frequency domain or in the time domain by [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the time based excitation function and the [impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) of the system.